# iOS PWA Audio Restrictions

Tags: javascript, ios, html, audio, socket.io

I'm making a platform which involves the server triggering Audio to be played with Socket.io. I'm trying to make a PWA for iOS using similar code, but it just doesn't work and I've heard that Safari requires user interaction (I am using this with the full screen PWA meta tag, not through Safari directly). It works fine on the latest version of Chrome on desktop.

Is there anyway to make this work?

Web Interface (uses same audio 
playing and socket.io code): https://github.com/archiebaer/bithop-web-interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Safari restricts audio playing quite a lot. It seems in your scenario, there is no work around unfortunately.

Comment: Okay. :(
Is there any alternative?